# jQuery does not get correctly values of all checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-events

I have a list of checkboxes initially checked as follow:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="capacity" value="16" checked> 16 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="capacity" value="32" checked> 32 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="capacity" value="64" checked> 64 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="capacity" value="128" checked> 128 <br>
```

Each time a checkbox is checked or unchecked, I want to update the `capacity` list again, therefore, I use (with a little bit of repeating the code):

```
$('input[name="capacity"]').change(function() {
   var capacity = $('input[name="capacity"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
   console.log(capacity);
})
```

However, the capacity still contains value of last unchecked checkbox. When I unchecked 128 -> `capacity = ["16","32","64","128"]`. Then, I unchecked 32 -> `capacity =["16","32","64"]`

I don't understand this strange behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the second `capacity` shadowing the first? Try removing the `var` keyword inside the `change` callback.

Comment: @andars I am sorry. My post was not clear, I will update it right now

Comment: Seems to work fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/5cc2aa3g/

Comment: It's as @andars said, @DucCuong never replaces the array by making it local with the `var` keyword

Comment: @RickHitchcock OK. It works correctly know. What I didn't notice is that in my code, I use `mousedown` instead of `change` for tracking checboxes' events. Maybe I should delete this question